# Rails not including modules on Models when run in Rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3.2.16, I have a model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  module Testmodule
    def testmethod
      puts "It's included"
    end
  end
  include Testmodule
end
```

when I run `bundle exec rails c`, I can type `Person.new.testmethod` and get the expected result

If I create a small rake task:

```
task :myraketask => :environment do
  Person.new.testmethod
end
```

I receive an error that testmethod isn't defined on Person.

However, if I explicitely set eager loading in the rake task, it will work:

```
task :myraketask => :environment do
  Rails.application.eager_load!
  Person.new.testmethod
end
```

If I create a brand new Rails project, I cannot replicate the error.  Can anybody point out to me what may be wrong in my project that is causing the error in the first rake task?

Comment: I think - not sure though - that your module should be defined outside of the Person class. If you want to keep that module in this class, you may have to use `include Person::Testmodule`

Comment: +1 we should consider name-spaces while including modules through class folder.